# trouble compiling app to add activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

as posts are limited in size on this platform I will post in parts first my mainactivity.java file package com.cancunsteve.aboutcancunsteve;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.MainActivity;
import android.NewActivity2;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
    NewActivity2.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: part of manifest
<application
..
android:supportsRtl="true"
..
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
   ..
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".NewActivity2"
android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<meta-data
android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
...

Comment: cannot find symbol class intent; NewActivity2; variable ActivityMain

Comment: By the way, you asked the same question twice. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: You seem new to Android, I recommend watching tutorials or reading about it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `NewActivity2` class/activity

Answer (score 0):

Your import is wrong for the `NewActivity2`, I doubt it is part of the android package.